# How to reduce Content-Range header using nginx serving webm?

Tags: nginx, video, video-streaming, video.js, webm

I have `nginx` serving `webm` files. I'm using `video.js` player for watching embedded videos at my website.

Everytime I seek video, I have to wait. For example, if video is 40 minutes (76 mb) long and I want to watch from 35th minute, I click at duration bar and wait until browser downloads ~10 mb. After that chunk loaded, I can continue watching.

I'm looking the way to reduce that chunk size to, let's say, 1 mb. Because I don't want to wait several seconds/minutes each time I seek the video.

Any way for that? I believe `nginx` is responsible for that, since files served directly from disk.

I tried `max_ranges 1024000;` but I believe it's for something else, because nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with Nginx.  It has to do with how your video is encoded.

First, make sure the WebM container is set up correctly.  For that, use mkclean.  https://www.matroska.org/downloads/mkclean.html

If that doesn't solve it for you, you might have to re-encode your video with more keyframes.  For that, you can use FFmpeg.

Comment: Yeah I tried mkclean. Nothing changed after I generated new file with this tool. Regarding keyframes.. I should change GOP size, right? Let's say, if using `-framerate 30`, then should use `-g 60`? As a result, chunk size should be decreased?

Comment: @JohnDoe GOP size of 60 is plenty low.  If that isn't working, it might actually just be an issue with the browser.  (Chrome is known to have a lot of problems here.)